# How to disable time in Bootstrap DateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I wanna use bootstrap datetimepicker without select time but it is not working. I gave false value to the pickTime parameter but it is still not working. But Format and language parameters is working.

Here is the code!
How can i fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
         $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: "dd MM yyyy",
            pickTime: false,
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true,
            language: 'tr',
            pickerPosition: "bottom-right"          
            });
        });
</script>



<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>

     <span class="input-group-addon">Birtdate</span>
     <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">  </span>
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what bootstrap datetimepicker script are you using?  Can you post a link to its documentation?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle, because for me your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/uzj82mry/

Comment: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

Comment: sandeeproop code is working but i wanna disable time section in the picker. I didnt do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many datetimepicker plugin, so you need to details what plugin you used.
If you use the plugin from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.
I think, you may use wrong its option : read more at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/. Here I removed almost, and just keep one:

```
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy"         
    });
```

Comment: Okey i found the solution. i checked the document in the http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and i show a parameter with the name "minview" and i gave its value 2. That's it! Thank you!

Comment: minView: 2, startView: 2

Comment: For eonasdan datetimepicker version 4.14.30 "pickTime" attribute doesnt work. You need to use "format" function set to "YYYY-MM-DD" for example.

Answer (score 10):

try this remove pickTime Option and use minview : 2

```
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    minView : 2
  });
});
```

Comment: minview didn't work for me, minView (capital V) did.Thanks!

Comment: You're the best! Looked everywhere, I'm using this in Yii2 framework and had to add it like `'minView' => 2,` to the `pluginOptions` array.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below code, which will show only the date view, when the calendar is pulled down.

```
    $(function () {
     $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            startView: 'month',
            minView: 'month',
            autoclose: true          
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this website online it disables the time picker

```
http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false
    });
  });
</script>
```